# How to Get a typed DTO with only some fields from Elasticsearch with Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to `Get` a result from Elasticsearch 1.7.0 using NEST 1.7.1. My documents contain many fields, but I'm interested in only one of them. I would prefer to get a typed result representing a partial document.

I'm using something along the lines of this code:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url)).SetDefaultIndex("MyIndex");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var result = client.Get<MyDtoPartial>(g => g
    .Type("myDocType")
    .Id("abcdefg123456")
    .Fields("doc.subids")
);
```

Where `MyDtoPartial` currently looks like this:

```
public class MyDtoPartial
{
    [JsonProperty("doc.subids")]
    public IList<string> SubIds { get; set; }

    // Other properties of my documents are not mapped, in this
    // context I only want the SubIds.
}
```

In the debugger I can drill into `result.Fields` and see that the first in that dictionary has a value rendered by the debugger along these lines:

```
{[doc.subids, [ "12354adsf-123fasd", "2134fa34a-213123" ...
```

I can also see the Elasticsearch request that was made, which was like this:

```
http://myserver:12345/MyIndex/myDocType/abcdefg123456?fields=doc.subids
```

And it returns this type of json:

```
{
    "_index": "MyIndex",
    "_type": "myDocType",
    "_id": "abcdefg123456",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "fields": {
        "doc.subids": ["12354adsf-123fasd",
        "2134fa34a-213123",
        "adfasdfew324-asd"]
     }
}
```

So I have a feelling my *request* is okay, because that *is* the kind of response I'd expect.

However, **my goal was to get an instance of `MyDtoPartial` with a fully populated `SubIds` property**. However, the `result` doesn't seem to contain any kind of property of type `MyDtoPartial`.

I've gone through [the Nest `Get` docs](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/get.html), which actually led to the above code.

What is the proper way to `Get` a proper typed single document with only some fields from Elastic with Nest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mention `.Fields(...)`, `Source` will always be `null`. If you remove `.Fields(...)`, then `Source` should be of type `MyDtoPartial` and give you the desired results. The reason you still get `Source` as `null` may be because in the mapping of `myDocType`, `_source` field is disabled. Check the definition of `myDocType` by executing `GET <index name>/_mapping/myDocType`. If `_source` is disabled, there is no way Nest will give you a concrete object of `MyDtoPartial` in its response for this type.

If you have `_source` enabled but only want to fetch a subset of fields, then you can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead of `fields` to specify which fields you want and which ones you do not want to be returned in the response.

```
var result = client.Get<MyDtoPartial>(g => g
    .Type("myDocType")
    .Id("abcdefg123456")
    .SourceInclude("doc.subids")
);
```

Now `result.Source` will be an object of `MyDtoPartial` where all fields except `SubIds` will be `null` and `SubIds` will have the expected value.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally focussed to much on `Source`, probably because of a lack of Elastic understanding. I don't *mean* to get the entire source, I *meant* to get only certain fields. So I don't want to remove `Fields(...)`, I only did so for testing purposes. I'll try to update my question accordingly.

Comment: If you mention `.Fields(...)`, AFAIK, there is no way you can get an object of `MyDto`; you'll have to parse `result.Fields` yourself.

Comment: But do you have `_source` enabled? If you do, then there is another option that I can elaborate upon so that you don't need to parse `result.Fields`.

Comment: Yes, I think so, if I exeucte `GET MyIndex/_mapping/docType` I see that `_source` is set to be `compressed`, and if I use our *head* plugin to query these documents I do see a `"_source"` with all of my fields, including the one I'm trying to retrieve. (It's rather big, which is why I don't want to query the entire document if I don't have to.)

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help, and bearing with my somewhat chameleonic question. The `SourceInclude` approach does sort effect, though my property is not yet filled. However, I suspect that might be a consequence of something lost in translation from my real scenario to my SO question. I'll have to dive a lot deeper (and possibly create a real repro) to find out how this will work for my actual scenario.

Comment: Turned out the period in `doc.subids` actually meant I had a nested document, and needed to restructure my DTOs slightly as well. In any case, the `SourceInclude` thing was the main culprit, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, having a dot in the field name is a problem with Elasticsearch 2.x. It is fine though in Elasticsearch 1.x.